# I want to understand MySql 5.5 source code in details specially sql_parse.cc file

Tags: mysql

I want to understand MySql 5.5 source code in details specially sql_parse.cc file.

Can anybody tell me where to get the resources or any link?

Comment: What exactly do you want to understand? I don't think you will get many answers with this hazy a requirement. Can you clarify?

Comment: No downvote. What resources you are asking for? Just study the source code.

Comment: You mean [this sql_parse.cc](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/trunk/view/head:/sql/sql_parse.cc)? Realistically unless MySQL themselves provide documentation or architectual overview I doubt you'll find any resources. What exactly are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: I want to understand the code means what does every variable and function do and all that..

Comment: Is there any documentation for MySql code??

Answer (score 2):

Here's where you should start your research: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but not much in details...I want details view of sql_parse.cc file...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sure. There's a discussion list http://lists.mysql.com/internals where can ask this question